# How to validate Hierarchy of three columns in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel; which has two sheets:

The first sheet is:  'Jurisdictions'
Which has three columns:

Country (Column B), State (Column C) and City (Column D)

This sheet has single entry for each city.

But, as each city is listed on separate row, the names of state and country(To which cities belong) can get repeated on multiple rows.

For Ex:

```
U.S. --> New York --> Buffalo

U.S. --> New York --> Manhattan
```

(These are my two rows)

I have another sheet: Sheet1;

Here also I have same three columns; (and 20 some other columns)

These three columns I shall validate with three columns in 'Jurisdictions' sheet.
(Only few 'Jurisdictions' are listed in Sheet1; and those can be in any order and can be for any country)

The validation Rules are:

1) For Country

-- Country name should be a single value only.

-- Should match with name under 'Country' column in Jurisdiction sheet.

-- Cases should be neglected(Uppercase/Lowercase)

2) State

-- Can have one or Multiple values separated only with semicolon (To separate those values with semicolon I have written a different code and it works fine)

-- The entry in this cell even can be 'All'

-- All the state names should match with states listed under 'state' column of Jurisdiction sheet. (If multiple entries are listed; those should be first separated based on delimeter - semicolon and then to be compared)

-- Cases should be neglected(Uppercase/Lowercase); Extra spaces before and after state names should be trimmed.

3) City

-- Can have one or Multiple values separated only with semicolon

-- The entry in this cell can be 'All' also.

-- All the city names should match with cities listed under 'City' column of Jurisdiction sheet. (If multiple entries are listed; those should be first separated based on delimeter - semicolon and then to be compared)

-- Cases should be neglected(Uppercase/Lowercase); Extra spaces before and after state names should be trimmed.

I have written the code which validates individual column.

But It's not sufficient..!!!

I have to validate hierarchy too..!!

i.e.

```
U.S. --> New York --> Buffalo

U.S. --> New York --> Manhattan; Buffalo

India --> Karnataka;Maharashtra --> All
```

The code I have written to validate these individual columns is as follows;

```
'********************************************************
'validate the 'Country' column in Sheet1, such that; It matches with one of the Country names and must exist
'********************************************************

    'Get the last row
    'Dim lastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    nLastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Jurisdictions").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim c As Range

    'Turn screen updating off to speed up macro code.
    'User won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        Dim rngFnder As Range
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("B2:B" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(c)

            If rngFnder Is Nothing Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next


'********************************************************
'validate the 'State(multiples)' column in the Questions sheet, such that:
'-   State name matches with one of the state names or
'-   State name is set as 'All'
'********************************************************

    Dim stString As String
    Dim stArray() As String

    'Get the last row
    'Dim lastRow As Integer
    'LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'nLastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Jurisdictions").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim e As Variant

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
        stString = c
        stArray() = Split(stString, ";")
        For Each e In stArray()
            e = Trim(e)

            'Dim rngFnder As Range
            On Error Resume Next

                Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("C2:C" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(e)

                If rngFnder Is Nothing And c <> "All" Then
                    c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If

            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    Next

'********************************************************
'validate the City(Multiples) column in the Questions sheet, such that:
'-   City name matches with one of the Cities or
'-   City name is set as 'All'
'********************************************************

'Dim stString As String
'Dim stArray() As String

'Get the last row
'Dim lastRow As Integer
'LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'nLastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Jurisdictions").UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Dim c As Range
'Dim d As Range
'Dim e As Variant

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    stString = c
    stArray() = Split(stString, ";")
    For Each e In stArray()
        e = Trim(e)

        'Dim rngFnder As Range
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("D2:D" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(e)

            If rngFnder Is Nothing And c <> "All" Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
Next
```

I am facing the problem when I try to combine all the above codes into a single code module.
As am newbie to Excel vba I don't know how to refer adjacent cells; how to concatenate strings (In 'State' and 'City' columns I have to first separate those States/Cities based on semicolon if there are multiple entries) from three different columns and compare those with three different columns.

Can some one help me to write the proper code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made another amendment to the code. My previous edit didn't work as planned because I mixed up the variable names. (As a side note, this demonstrates why it's important to use easily identifiable variable names. Just calling a variable `c` or `e` can confuse the reader).

I still don't completely understand what you need with the `all` condition.  See if you can get this part to work, and then we can try tackling the `all` situation.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim nLastRowSheet2 As Long
Dim rngFnder As Range
Dim strFndAddress As String
Dim stArray() As String
Dim c As Range
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
nLastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    stString = c
    stArray() = Split(stString, ";")
    For Each e In stArray()
        e = Trim(e)

        strFndAddress = ""
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("D2:D" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(e)

            If rngFnder Is Nothing And c <> "All" Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed

            Else
                strFndAddress = rngFnder.Address
                Do
                    If c.Offset(, -1) = rngFnder.Offset(, -1) And c.Offset(, -2) = rngFnder.Offset(, -2) Then
                        strFndAddress = ""
                        Exit Do
                    Else

                        Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("D2:D" & nLastRowSheet2).FindNext(rngFnder)

                    End If
                Loop While Not rngFnder Is Nothing And rngFnder.Address <> strFndAddress
            End If

            If rngFnder.Address = strFndAddress Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set c = Nothing
        strFndAddress = ""
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I just edited the code again. Please try this new code to remove the infinite loop. I had my checking variable in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT BASED ON NEW INFORMATION:

I've amended the code below to continue iterating through the Jurisdiction range until it finds a match. If not, it will return a red color.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim nLastRowSheet2 As Long
Dim rngFnder As Range
Dim strFndAddress As String
Dim stArray() As String
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
nLastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    stString = c
    stArray() = Split(stString, ";")
    For Each e In stArray()
        e = Trim(e)

        strFndAddress = ""
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("D2:D" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(e)

            If rngFnder Is Nothing And c <> "All" Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed

            Else
                Do
                    If c.Offset(, -1) = rngFnder.Offset(, -1) And c.Offset(, -2) = rngFnder.Offset(, -2) Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        strFndAddress = c.Address
                        Set c = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("D2:D" & nLastRowSheet2).FindNext(c)

                    End If
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> strFndAddress
            End If

            If c.Address = strFndAddress Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
Next
```

This can be handled most easily by working in reverse order of the hierarchy. As mentioned, in the `Jurisdictions` worksheet, countries and states both repeat, but cities are unique. So, it would behoove us to search for the city first. Once the city is found, we can then check if the city and state will match. A sample code entry is below. Let me know if it works.

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    stString = c
    stArray() = Split(stString, ";")
    For Each e In stArray()
        e = Trim(e)

        'Dim rngFnder As Range
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnder = Sheets("Jurisdictions").Range("D2:D" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(e)

            If rngFnder Is Nothing And c <> "All" Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
        If c.Offset(,-1) = rngFnder.Offset(,-1) AND c.Offset(,-2) = rngFnder.Offset(,-2) then
            'Do Nothing, or enter code if they all match
        Else
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End if
            End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
Next
```

The `Offset` method moves from one range to another based on `(Rows_to_Move, Columns_to_Move)`. In the code, I requested that variable `C` check 1 cell to its left and compare that with 1 cell to the left of the found range in `Jurisdictions` (checks the state), then I repeated that for 2 cells to the left. If they all match, the code does nothing. Otherwise, the cell is highlighted red.

Please let me know of follow up questions.

Comment: Thanks a ton Sir; 
This code works fine :)

There is just a single challenge:

This code compares the records from 'Sheet1' with those in 'Jurisdictions' Sheet; with their first occurrence only. When it comes across some city name say 'Santa Cruz' then it compares the hierarchy of the cell from 'Jurisdiction' sheet with first occurrence only... if the first occurrence is wrong; the cell interior color is changed to red; and it fetches next record from 'Sheet1' for comparison. 
There are such several cities with same names in different states/countries..

Comment: I was trying to modify the code with my other requirements. Requirement (1) If the 'City' has record as 'All' then It's state can be anything (one or multiple) But it's next hierarchy should be correct. That is (Country -> State -> All) should be correct. (As 'jurisdictions' has 8000+ (and still increasing) records we can't add all 'All' cases to it) and another thing is that; If (either) Multiple states are listed under 'state' cell(Or it's value is 'All')  then the adjacent cell for city should have value 'All' only. Am not understanding where to add this code :(

Comment: I'm responding in another answer below so that it doesn't get too cluttered.